# Flask syntax error on database initialization

Tags: python, database, flask

If anyone saw my other question, I was able to fix the issue, but a new one arose within the same function that I can't figure out.

This function seems syntactically correct to me:

```
def init_db():
    """Initializes the database."""
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ad60ea155641> in <module>()
----> 1 init_db()

/Users/andrew/code/pos_system/routes.py in init_db()
     31         db = get_db()
     32         with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
---> 33             db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
     34         db.commit()
     35

OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

I don't see an errors with the parentheses on line 33...

Comment: The error is not in the python code - it is inside the `schema.sql`.

Comment: @alecxe that was the issue, thanks.  How did you know the syntax error was within the schema?

Comment: By the exception type - it is `OperationalError` (not a built-in one), not `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [@alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) in the comments:

> The error is not in the python code - it is inside the `schema.sql`. You can tell because the exception type was `OperationalError` (which is not a built-in python exception), not `SyntaxError`